# Origin of the D1 line of sodium

Tags: spectroscopy, atomic-structure

According to the [fine structure formula for exact energies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_structure#Exact_relativistic_energies) (Sommerfield formula)

$$E_{jn} = -m_\mathrm{e}c^2\left[1 - \left(1 + \left[\frac{\alpha}{n - j - \frac 1 2 + \sqrt{\left(j + \frac 1 2\right)^2 - \alpha^2}}\right]^2\right)^{-1/2}\right],$$

the energy depends only on $n$ and the absolute value of the total angular momentum $j.$ In the absence of magnetic field, there are two spectral lines for the sodium atom $\mathrm{D1}$ and $\mathrm{D2}.$ I am confused about the origin of the $\mathrm{D1}$ line since it corresponds to a transition $3P_{1/2}\rightarrow 3S_{1/2},$ both states have total angular momentum $j=1/2.$ However, these should be degenerate according to Dirac theory.

What am I missing here? Is the $\mathrm{D1}$ line purely due to electron-electron repulsion inside the sodium atom?

Comment: [This link](https://www.chem.uci.edu/~unicorn/249/Handouts/RWFSodium.pdf) says spin-orbit coupling is the source of the splitting.

Comment: The equation you give is for a one-electron atom, if you have more electrons, such as in sodium, the potential is no longer purely Coulombic and the levels split. Note that in hydrogen this also happens due to QED effects and this gives rise to the famous Lamb shift.

Comment: I have seen that, but since the spin-orbit coupling, along with other effects, arises from the non-relativistic limit of Dirac's equation, it looks wrong to me to say that spin-orbit coupling is the origin of the D1 line. The exact solution to Dirac equation, as seen above, predicts that the 3S1/2 and the 3P1/2 are degenerate. That's why I am confused

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I think you're right, but I just wanted to check, since I did not find this written in the quantum mechanics textbooks I know. I believe the Lamb's shift should be of the same order as the hyperfine structure, right? If so, the origin of the D1 line is due to electron-electrion repulsion.

Comment: More or less. More precisely, it is caused by a phase shift in the electron wave function as the electron scatters from the ionic core. The magnitude of this phase shift is related to the [quantum defect in Rydberg's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_defect).

Comment: OK, thank you. I didn't know about that. Is this related to the fact that the nucleus is an extended object rather than a point-like positive charge?